# как подвинуть рекламу admob

Tags: android, admob

добавил рекламу Admob все работает хорошо, но как сделать так чтоб при появлении рекламы главное активити поднималось выше чтоб реклама не перекрывала кнопки?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back2"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="113dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button_reset"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_DM"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="4"
                    android:hint="@string/DM"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:maxLength="3"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/black" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_MT"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="4"
                    android:hint="@string/MT"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:maxLength="3"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/black" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_MSDF"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="4"
                    android:hint="@string/MSDF"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:maxLength="3"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/black" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_IBSDF"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="4"
                    android:hint="@string/IBSDF"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:maxLength="3"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/black" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_Final"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="4"
                    android:hint="@string/Final"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:maxLength="3"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/black" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_AVG"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="4"
                    android:hint="@string/AVG"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:maxLength="9"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/black" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_U_need"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="4"
                    android:hint="@string/U_need"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:maxLength="12"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/black" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_reset"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_cached_black_36dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text=" " />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого надо поместить основной экран и рекламный блок в одну разметку (например RelativeLayout) и указать рекламе быть снизу от разметки основной (аттрибут `android:layout_above` со значением равным id баннера `@id/adview` и прижаться к низу контейнера.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/MAIN_AD_UNIT_ID"/>

    <Linearlayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/adview">
            ...тут основная разметка активити.
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: сделал, так и было, только не помогло

Comment: @java, приведите тогда свою разметку. Я эту скопировал со своего рабочего приложения и всё там как надо работало.

Comment: добавил в вопрос вроде

Comment: @java, добавьте во внутрениий рэлатив атрибут как у меня в ответе: `android:layout_above="@id/banner"`

Comment: сделал, не знаю сработало или нет, просто под рекламой мой background остался так должно быть или как? просто обычно в приложениях сколько видел реклама в самом низу и не видно заднего фона

Comment: @java, просто перенесите фон во втрой рэлатив...

Comment: перенес, теперь когда нет инета место рекламы заливается белым цветом(

Comment: @java, без инета можно программно, чрез LayoutParams проставить нулевую высоту баннеру.

Comment: это в главном классе прописать надо?

Comment: @java, Можно попробовать изначально проставить нулевую высоту и в слушателе прихода рекламы высоту проставить нужную. Но, может быть, реклама не захочет так грузиться. Поэксперементируйте. А писать где?.. Ну, смотря как у вас всё организовано. Наверное, в активити...

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь, вы единственный кто мне помогает и отвечает на мои вопросы, прошлый раз тоже вы спасли меня)))

Comment: @java, пж-та) Вы просто забываете на свои вопросы ставить метки `android` и `java` вот на них и мало просмотров и нема ответов. Кстати, теперь вам репутация позволяет голосовать за вопросы и ответы)

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь )))))))